# Undefined binding detected

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

I'm trying to get data from my PostgreSQL database via Knex to my front end, but I get this error:

```
Error: Undefined binding(s) detected when compiling SELECT.
Undefined column(s): [mdn]
query: select "mdn" from "asurion"."user_info" where "mdn" = ?
```

Here is my backend function that makes a query:

```
function prepareSearchResponse(dbResponse) {
  return dbResponse.map((dbobj) => {
    const pInfo =
      dbobj.message_json.sdes &&
      dbobj.message_json.sdes.events.find((obj) => obj.personalInfo);
    return {
      realTimeId: dbobj.mdn,
      endTime: dbobj.message_json.info.endTime,
      startTime: dbobj.message_json.info.startTime,
      conversation_id: pInfo ? pInfo.personalInfo.personalInfo.surname : "n/a",
      skill: dbobj.message_json.info.latestSkillName,
      operatorName: dbobj.message_json.info.latestAgentFullName,
      operatorId: dbobj.message_json.info.latestAgentId,
      entryPoint: pInfo ? pInfo.personalInfo.personalInfo.name : "n/a",
      ipAddress: dbobj.message_json.info.ipAddress,
      messageRecords: dbobj.message_json.messageRecords,
    };
  });
}

const getDeviceId = (req, res, db) => {
  let rId = req.params.rId;
  db.from("asurion.user_info")
    .where({ mdn: rId })
    .select("mdn")
    .then((items) => {
      if (items.length) {
        res.json(utils.prepareSearchResponse(items));
      } else {
        res.json({ dataExists: "false" });
      }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
};
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It looks like your `rId` parameter is `undefined`. Try to `console.log` it before `knex` execution and then to check if it's passing correctly.

Comment: yea it showing undefined. what parameter can I put in there to get the data from the db to appear onto the front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your router parameter is missing. Assuming Express, this would normally be defined like so:

```
app.get('/devices/:rId', getDeviceId);
```

If your route definition is correct, it's possible you aren't passing it in the URL of the GET request. So you might expect to see:

```
http://localhost:3000/devices/1234
```

or similar. If this id is missing, that would cause `rId` to be undefined.

I wonder a bit about your query too. You seem to be asking for only one column, the value of which you already know. So instead of:

```
db.from("asurion.user_info")
  .where({ 'mdn': rId })
  .select("mdn")
```

you might like to start with all columns:

```
db
  .withSchema("asurion")
  .select("*")
  .from("user_info")
  .where({ "mdn": rId })
```

and narrow it from there as necessary.